# Sterescopic vision in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, augmented-reality, matlab-cvst, stereoscopy

I am looking to overlay a virtual cursor on to a stereoscopic image in MATLAB. Needless to say, the cursor should look stereoscopic too. I need the cursor to be able to move up and down, left and right and farther and closer to the camera. How would I go about this?
Based on my research, I'm guessing I would need to:
1. Perform camera calibration (for each of the two cameras + stereo calibration)
2. Stereo image rectification
3. Generate cursor
4. Use GUI inputs to control the cursor's movement
Am I right? If so, how would I go about steps 3 and 4 and if not, why not?
Any help would be appreciated. I would guess that this shouldn't be too rare to find. If you know of any kind of software that already does this, I'd really appreciate it.